# Visual Code: Debug multiple servers concurrently from launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

> I have an **API server** and a **WEB_SERVER**.
>
> In package.json, using 'concurrently', I have no problem **running both servers concurrently** (from their entry files of /bin/server.js & /bin/api.js respectively).
>
> However, when using Visual Code, no break points in the api server are
>   hit when **in debug mode** (Breakpoints in WEB_SERVER are hit).
>
> Here is my launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "API+WEB_SERVER",
      "configurations": [ "API", "WEB_SERVER" ]
    }
  ],
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "API",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program":  "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\api.js",
      "stopOnEntry": true,
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": null,
      "runtimeExecutable": null,
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy"
      ],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "externalConsole": false,
      "sourceMaps": false,
      "outDir": null
    },
```

---

```
    {
      "name": "WEB_SERVER",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program":  "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\server.js",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": null,
      "runtimeExecutable": null,
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy"
      ],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "externalConsole": false,
      "sourceMaps": false,
      "outDir": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Attach",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 5858,
      "address": "localhost",
      "restart": false,
      "sourceMaps": false,
      "outDir": null,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "remoteRoot": null
    }
  ]
}
```

**QUESTION:**

What is the correct way to format .vscode's launch.json, in order to **run both servers concurrently and debug accordingly**.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out. Instead of deleting the question, I thought I'd share the solution for anyone else having this problem.

My launch.json configuration is correct, I needed to select the correct config selection from the drop down before starting debug mode. Naturally the correct choice is API+WEB_SERVER.

[image]